# Encoding issue in html:form with Struts 1.2

Tags: jsp, utf-8, character-encoding, weblogic, struts-1

I have an application with Struts 1.2 and in a .jsp I've created a form using html tag, this is part of my code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html-el" prefix="html" %>
...
<html:form action="/myAction" method="post">
...
  <display:table name="ListOfEntries" sort="external" requestURI="/myEntryAction.do" uid="row">
  ...
    <display:column titleKey="label.label" sortable="true" sortProperty="label">
      <span id="staticlabel<c:out value="${row.id}" />">
        <bean:write name="row" property="label" />
      </span>
      <html:text name="MyEntryForm" property="editedEntry.label" value="${row.label}" disabled="true" style="display:none" size="35"/>
    </display:column>
```

So, when a edit an entry with a special character `Ç`, in my `MyEntryForm` I get it as `Ã`.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that I'm using Weblogic.

Comment: pls more informations about your data flow. do you save the data in a database? perhaps is your db is not utf-8 ready.

Comment: The problem is when I edit the entry, before that the character is fine, in database is stored as `Ç`. Of course, if I save the edited entry, in database is store wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem.

In the question I forgot to mention that I'm using Weblogic as server. Debugging with Firefox or Chrome I checked that the request from my browser was correct, with the correct character, so it had to be the server.

In my project, I have a weblogic.xml, with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90
    http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<description>My Struts Application</description>

<context-root>RootOfMyApplication</context-root>

<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

And I adding this the problem was solved:

```
<charset-params>
    <input-charset>
        <resource-path>/*</resource-path>
        <java-charset-name>UTF-8</java-charset-name>
    </input-charset>
</charset-params>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see here several possible issues and solutions.

1) In order to correctly decode an HTML file, your should **tell to your browser what encoding to use**. You can tell it to him by setting the [charset parameter](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index) or by setting [meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp). In your HTML, add this meta tag and see if that makes it look right in your browser:

for HTML4: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

for HTML5: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

---

2) **The HTML meta tag is ignored when the page is served over HTTP**. It's only been used when the page is by the client saved as a HTML file on local disk system and then opened by a file:// URI in browser.

Therefore it can be that HTTP request body encoding is apparently not been set to UTF-8. The request body encoding needs to be set by

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

---

3) **Change the database connection encoding**

Following command should be used always once after opening the database connection to [UTF-8](http://www.unicode.org):

```
...
mysql_connect();
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

---

4) **Check the encoding of your database**. You can change the encoding of the database with:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

---

5) Also the **file should be recorded in UTF-8 format**. For example, in Eclipse: left-click on the file -> Properties -> Check out -> Text file encoding. Or do it in Notepad++.

---

So these are the most common issues. If it will not work, then provide us please with further information on your issue. But the main idea is actually always the same: *if you are bringing different tools together and combine them, every of them should know what encoding is used in the another tool*. And many of the problems are caused by one tool misunderstanding what encoding is actually used by another tool.

Comment: Great answer vlad_rad, thank you!. But I found what was the problem, I answer my own question.